# Determine if daylight saving time is active? SQL Server

Tags: sql, dst

I have a table with users, UTC time offset, and if they observe daylight saving time. Is there a built in way to get the correct user time?

Answer (score 4):

This won't work in all cases, but is a quick fix for those in the US w/ DST defined as between the 2nd Sunday of March and the 1st Sunday of November.

```
DECLARE @Date datetime2 = '2018-11-04 02:01:00'

SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN @Date between
            DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@Date), 3, (8 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@Date), 3, 1))) + 8, 02, 00, 00, 00)
            and
            DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@Date), 11, (8 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@Date), 11, 1))) + 1, 02, 00, 00, 00)
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END --Is it dst?
```

Answer (score 3):

The `sys.time_zone_info` table introduced in SQL 2016 allows to determine the offset from UTC and whether DST is currently in effect.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.time_zone_info
```

The query result will be:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Right now I'm doing this:

```
SELECT 
CASE USEDAYLIGHTSAVING
    WHEN 1 THEN
        CASE DATEDIFF(HH,GETUTCDATE(),GETDATE())
                -- I know the server is set to Mountan time and follows daylight saving time
                -- MDT = -6
                -- MST = -7
            WHEN -6 THEN 
                DATEADD(HH,TIMEZONEOFFSET+1,GETUTCDATE())
            ELSE 
                DATEADD(HH,TIMEZONEOFFSET,GETUTCDATE())
        END
    ELSE
            DATEADD(HH,TIMEZONEOFFSET,GETUTCDATE())
    END
FROM 
USERS
```

It works but if the server get's moved to another timezone or doesn't fallow daylight saving time I'm hosed.

Comment: So that you're aware, you also have a problem right at the DST shift. Most DST shifts are based on local time, so for example, for the two hours after the eastern timezone shifts for DST and before the mountain timezone does the same, you're off an hour for all eastern timezone times.

Comment: @chezy525 - You are correct. I think we all should pull an Arizona and just dump daylight savings time.

Comment: I would be so happy if we did! This *stuff* does nothing but give me headaches...

Answer (score 1):

> I have a table with users, UTC time offset, and if they observe daylight saving time. Is there a built in way to get the correct user time?

Different time zones around the world observe DST in different ways.  They start and stop at different times of the day.  Simply having an offset and DST flag is not enough to reliably convert.

Instead, you need a *time zone identifier*, such as `America/Los_Angeles`, or one of the others [listed here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).  Once you have that, you can use my [SQL Server Time Zone Support](https://github.com/mj1856/SqlServerTimeZoneSupport) project to do the conversions.

Answer (score 1):

using SQL 2016 system table (noted by @anacv),

To get current time for a timezone (DST or PDT) if server/timestamp is GMT

```
declare @currentDatetime datetime
declare @tzone varchar(100)
set @tzone = 'Pacific Standard Time'
set @currentDatetime = dateadd(MINUTE, (select cast(right(current_utc_offset,2) as int) FROM sys.time_zone_info where name=@tzone) , dateadd(HOUR,(select cast(left(current_utc_offset,3) as int) FROM sys.time_zone_info where name=@tzone), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
```

Comment: This should be the real answer.  Although needs to be modified to include condition when is_currently_dst is 1.

Comment: @Riccarr I believe the current_utc_offset adjusts automaticall if is_currently_dst is 1.