# Determining remote daylight saving in sql server

Tags: sql-server, timezone, dst

I want to determine the if daylight saving time is active or not, but in a region different to where my server is located.

My problem is I want to check the daylight saving of London and my server is in Canada; is it possible to find the daylight saving of a different time zone?

Comment: refer duplicate (no answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781121/determine-if-daylight-saving-time-is-active-sql-server. The short answer is that there is nothing built in. Windows processes DST using "lookup tables" stored in the registry which are not normally accessible from T-SQL.

Answer (score 5):

You need to deploy a table of DST and look up the DST time for the region you want. DST are published by various organizations and refreshed periodically. What you need to understand is that DST cannot be determined by an algorithm, it can only be looked up as is set by various legislative bodies for various regions, and changes frequently. For example here is the [current 2013 DST table](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2013.html). Maintaining your application's DST look-up table current would be a periodic task for your application.

Comment: Deploying a table of time zone data in your database is not usually a good idea.  It will end up being an artifact that you have to maintain manually, and over time you will find it to be inaccurate.

Comment: I stand by my recommendation

Comment: @RemusRusanu Do you know where we can get the DST SQL script for a specific year like 2015?

Comment: Things that change arbitrarily require maintenance.  It's just a matter of who does the maintenance.  If you can find a reliable source, I've found that importing it regularly is the lowest maintenance option other than querying an external source in real time.  It's not really any different than postal code data.

Answer (score 1):

On Sql Server 2016:

With sys.time_zone_info now you can query if a specific timezone is currently on DST.

```
select * from sys.time_zone_info
```

Here you have an example result

```
name                    current_utc_offset    is_currently_dst
Aleutian Standard Time  -09:00                1
Hawaiian Standard Time  -10:00                0
Marquesas Standard Time -09:30                0
Alaskan Standard Time   -08:00                1
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was down-voted.  The OP didn't ask for a way to know DST for an arbitrary time - which this can't provide.  Perhaps the data source isn't reliable????  It would be nice to know.  On its face the solution looks viable.

Answer (score -1):

Here’s a crude IsDST for SQL Server…

```
CAST((DATEPART(month, DATEADD(week, -1, <DateTime>)) + 2) % 13 / 5 AS bit) AS IsDST
```

Yields 0 for Standard Time Nov 8 – Mar  7, and 1 for Daylight Time Mar 8 – Nov 7.

Comment: This might work (this year?) for Canada, but DST starts March 29 2015 in London.

Comment: DST rules should not be enshrined into SQL in this manner.  They can easily change.