# Show time according to brazil current time zone (including daylight saving)

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on MVC 4 application.This application  work according to Brazil time zone.
So i have made column datatype datetimeoffset.

Now my question is how will i convert this time according to brazil current time including daylight saving if they have at time.

Eg : current time in india is `'2013-10-25 12:24:33.2343750 +05:30'` but how do i show this time in brazil . I can't convert like `SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),'-03:00')` in sql server as they have day light saving now.

Please give me some advice that how do i solve this problem.
Do i have to do something on code or in sql server ?

Answer (score 0):

You could  save UTC 0 in your database. In code you then convert to datetime and subtract 3 hours (datetime.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0,3,0,0,0);) 
Substract hours depending on the month of the timesavings.

Or u could check out this site to solve it in SQL:
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1372/daylight-savings-time-functions-in-sql-server/

Comment: -3 hours is standard time zone for brazil.. but now because of day light saving brazil current offset is -2 hours..so how do i solve this

Comment: You can solve it in code by substracting the hours in code. You know when daylight savings starts and ends. 

Here is an issue about how to check if daylight saving is active. It might help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6781141/2914856